# Which will be more efficient for server to handle

Tags: mysql, database-design, web-applications, architecture, web2py

Let me say I have a billing program webapp which will serve all users to maintain Thier business.

Eg:
*Receipt No, qty, AMT, owner*.

Are 4 tupples.

Now when multiple people use same online software, we are identifying transaction of a organisation by owners name.

When he takes his organisation sales report it has filter rows by owner name condition.

So this is delaying the process.

If we make master slaves database
Then we need only 3 *Receipt No, qty, AMT*, tupples since we can identify organisation by database name.

Which will be more efficient for server to handle !

I also need all organisation reports too combined.

P.S: I am using mysql server for db and web2py platform.

Comment: With proper indexes the DBMS usually won't have much problems filtering the rows for an owner.

Comment: That's true. But do I have further options optimise it  !?